# Post method not called when redirected from previous controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp, spring-boot, servlets

So I have 3 jsp-forms. The first one with general information. On completetion of the first form it should based on the value of a dropdown return eather form 2 or form 3. So far so good, the object is correctly written to the db, the check is performed and the correct jsp-form is shown, but when the user fills in the second form, nothing happens, read the postmethod of the secondform isn't called.
Any tips on how to fix this problem would be greatly appreciated.
I've bin breaking my head and searching the internet for days but can't find a straight answer.

The GeneralController:

```
@Controller
public class GeneralController {

@Autowired
private GeneralRepo repo;

@GetMapping("new")
public String getNew(Map<String, Object> model) {
    WrapperClass wrapper = new WrapperClass();
    model.put("wrapperForm", wrapper);
    return "newRecord";
}

@PostMapping("new")
public String handlePost(@ModelAttribute("wrapperForm") WrapperClass wrapper)
{
    Address address = new Address(wrapper.getNameOrg(), wrapper.getStreet(),    wrapper.getNumber(), wrapper.getZip(),
            wrapper.getCity(), wrapper.getTelephone(), wrapper.getEmail());
    General general = new General(wrapper.getLanguage(), wrapper.getApplication(), wrapper.getNameKbo(), wrapper.getKboNumber(),
            address, wrapper.getApplicationType(), wrapper.getNotes(), null, null, null, null);
    String url;
    if (general.getApplicationType().equalsIgnoreCase("voortzetting")) {
        url = "invoices";
    } else {
        url = "employee";
    }
    repo.save(general);
    return "redirect:/" + url;
}
}
```

The Generalform:

```
 <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
    <%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Record Toevoegen</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/general.css">

    <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/modern-business.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/customUtilities.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/general.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="icon" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/vigilis.jpg" type="image/x-icon">
</head>
<body>
<%@include file="navigation.jsp" %>

<%--@elvariable id="wrapperForm" type=""--%>
<form:form method="post" commandName="wrapperForm">
    <table align="center" id="forms">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Taal:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form:select path="language" id="language" name="language">
                    <form:option value="Nederlands"/>
                    <form:option value="Français"/>
                    <form:option value="Deutsch"/>
                    <form:option value="English"/>
                </form:select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label>Type Aanvraag: </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form:select path="applicationType" id="type" name="type">
                    <form:option value="Nieuwe aanvraag"/>
                    <form:option value="Voortzetting"/>
                    <form:option value="Vrijwillige ontbinding"/>
                    <form:option value="Faillisement"/>
                </form:select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="nameKbo">KBO-Benaming</label>
            </td>
            <td colspan="3">
                <form:input path="nameKbo" id="nameKbo" type="text" name="nameKbo" required="required" size="100%"/>
            </td>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="kboNumber">KBO-Nummer:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form:input path="kboNumber" id="kboNumber" type="text" name="kboNumber"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="nameOrg">HandelsBenaming:</label>
            </td>
            <td colspan="3">
                <form:input path="nameOrg" id="nameOrg" type="text" name="nameOrg" size="100%"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Adres:</label>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <form:input path="street" id="street" name="street" type="text" placeholder="Straatnaam" size="100%"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form:input path="number" id="number" name="number" type="text" size="5"/>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <form:input path="zip" id="zip" name="zip" type="text" placeholder="Zip" size="5"/>
            </td>
            <td >
                <form:input path="city" id="city" name="city" type="text" placeholder="Stad" size="80%"/>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Contactgegevens:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form:input path="telephone" id="telephone" name="telephone" type="text" placeholder="Telefoonnummer"/>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <form:input path="email" id="email" name="email" type="e-mail" placeholder="E-mailadres" size="100%"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="notes" style="vertical-align: middle">Opmerkingen:</label>
            </td>
            <td colspan="3">
                <form:textarea path="notes" id="notes" name="notes" style="width: 100%"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td colspan="2" style="align-content: center;"><input type ="submit" value="Opslaan" class="button"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form:form>
    <%@include file="footer.jsp" %>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The InvoiceController:

```
@Controller
public class InvoiceController {
@Autowired
private GeneralRepo repo;

@GetMapping("invoices")
public String handleGetInvoice(Map<String, Object> model) {
    Invoices invoiced = new Invoices();
    model.put("invoiceForm", invoiced);
    return "invoices";
}

@PostMapping("invoices")
public String handlePost(@ModelAttribute("invoiceForm") Invoices invoiced, Map<String, Object> model) {
    General general = repo.findLast();
    general.setInvoice(invoiced);
    repo.save(general);
    System.out.println("invoice saved");
    return "redirect:/employee";
}
}
```

The Invoiceform:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"  %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>Facturen</title>

    <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/modern-business.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/customUtilities.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/general.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="icon" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/vigilis.jpg" type="image/x-icon">
</head>
<body>
<!-- Navigation -->
<%@include file="navigation.jsp" %>

<%--@elvariable id="invoiceForm" type=""--%>
    <form:form action="invoices" method="post" commandName="invoiceForm">
        <table align="center" id="forms">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>Ontvangen:</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form:select path="received" id="received" name="received">
                        <form:option value="Ok"/>
                        <form:option value="Niet Ok"/>
                        <form:option value="Niet Aanwezig"/>
                        <form:option value="Aanwezig"/>
                    </form:select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label>Status: </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form:select path="state" id="state" name="state">
                        <form:option value="In Behandeling"/>
                        <form:option value="Goedgekeurd"/>
                        <form:option value="Geweigerd"/>
                        <form:option value="Ingetrokken"/>
                        <form:option value="Moraliteitsonderzoek"/>
                    </form:select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>Aantal Vorig jaar:</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form:input path="last" id="last" type="text" name="last" required="required"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label>Aantal Andere jaren:</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form:input path="early" id="early" type="text" name="early" required="required"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>

                </td>
                <td><label>BevestigingsDatum:</label></td>
                <td><form:input path="confirmationDate" id="confirmationDate" type="date" name="confirmationDate"
                                required="required"/></td>
                </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td colspan="2" style="align-content: center;"><input type="submit" value="Opslaan" class="button"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>

<!-- Footer -->
<%@include file="footer.jsp" %>

<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

pass the complete URL inside return for example

```
return "http://localhost:8080/projectname/"+url;
```

Comment: ??? What good would that do? The secondform get's shown, it's the postMethod that dosn't work, I don't see how your sugestion would fix that